# When do we use of "2>&1" in practice?

Tags: linux, null, command, line

As far as I understand, "/dev/null 2>&1" makes the program silent (the whole output and errors are suppressed).
And what about "2>&1" without /dev/null ?
For example,

ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>&1

What the practical usage of "2>&1" without /dev/null? Does it make any sense?
(It gives the exact same output as:

ls -ld /tmp /tnt )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect to say that `"/dev/null 2>&1" makes the program silent`. In isolation, that expression is incomplete.  For example, `echo foo /dev/null 2>&1` Passes `foo` and `/dev/null` as arguments to `echo` and runs `echo` with its stderr stream redirected to its stdout.  On the other hand, it is more common to see:

```
echo foo > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Which redirects stdout to /dev/null, and then redirects stderr to stdout (which is now /dev/null, so both streams go go /dev/null).  Notice that order is significant, and `echo foo 2>&1 > /dev/null` will write the errors to the calling process' stdout while writing output to /dev/null.

A common reason to use this sort of stream duplication is when you want to control where output and errors go.  For example, if you want to apply a filter to stderr, you can discard the output and filter the errors with:

```
cmd 2>&1 > /dev/null | sed 's/^/ERROR: /g' >&2
```

This is a trivial example intended merely for demonstration.  To apply a filter to both streams independently, you can do things like:

```
{ cmd 2>&1 >&3 | sed 's/^/ERROR: /' >&2; } 3>&1 | sed 's/^/OUT:   /';
```

Answer (score 0):

`2>&1` says redirect `stdout` as well as `stderr` to the same file.

This is helpful in debugging usually.

Comment: "This is helpful in debugging usually."
Could you give a plain example?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to direct all the stderr to a separate error log file? I'm not sure how it's more helpful to have all the outputs mixed together in a single file. It makes it harder to find the error logs, doesn't it? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

What `2>&1` does is it makes the error messages go to the standard output stream.

What the cryptic symbol means is a longer explanation.

A process has two special output streams, called "standard output" (for regular output) and "standard error" (for error messages). These are separate so that the program can report errors on the terminal even if you redirect the regular output to a file.

Any open file stream has a number associated with it, this number is called "file descriptor" (fd for short). It's how the operating system keeps track of the files a process is working with. Standard output gets the number (file descriptor) 1, standard error gets the number (fd) 2.

`2>&1` sets up file descriptor 2 as a copy of file descriptor 1. If you've redirected the output to a file like /dev/null, fd 1 refers to an open file, and this will make fd 2 refer to the same open file.